# Validate that JSON array has one associative array with fixed integer value

Tags: php, arrays, json, validation

I am trying to validate some JSON using Opis's [package](https://github.com/opis/json-schema). I am trying to validate that an array has at least one associative array with an `id` of value `1`. Here is the code I've got:

```
    $json = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3
        ]
    ];

    $rules = [
        'type' => 'array',
        'contains' => [
            'type' => 'array',
            'properties' => [
                'id' => [
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'const' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'required' => ['id']
        ],
        'minContains' => 1,
    ];

    $validated = Common::validateJSON($json, json_encode($rules));
```

and here is the `validateJSON` method code:

```
public static function validateJSON($json, $rules)
{
    $validator = new Validator();

    // Validate
    $result = $validator->validate($json, $rules);

    if ($result->isValid()) {
        return true;
    }

    $errorMessages = [];

    if ($result->hasError()) {
        $formatter = new ErrorFormatter();

        $errorMessages[] = $formatter->format($result->error());
    }

    return $errorMessages;
}
```

so, in this case `$validated` returns:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "/" => array:1 [
      0 => "At least 1 array items must match schema"
    ]
  ]
]
```

changing `$rules` to this:

```
$rules = [
    'type' => 'array',
    'contains' => [
        'type' => 'array',
    ],
    'minContains' => 1,
];
```

returns the same result which is weird for me.

Changing `const` to any number doesn't change what is returned. So, my guess is that I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

I've been googling various things nothing helped. I've been looking at the JSON schema site, particularly [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html) but I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Before validating, as I am not json decoding the data as it is not coming from an http request, do this:

```
$json = json_encode($json);
$json = json_decode($json); // this, I think, will turn associative arrays into objects which makes it work
```

and the second `type` must be `object`.